# Merge two folders in Lotus Notes 8.5.3

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have a user who has got two folders called "CLIENTS" and "CLIENTS2". Now, I need to merge those two folers into a single one but cannot do that manually since there are hundreds of sub folders which would take forever to be moved. Is there any way I can do that by script? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In Notes, subfolders aren't really "inside" of each other.  I.e., if you see A folder XXX, with a subfolder YYY, what you really have is a folder named "XXX", and another folder named "XXX\YYY".  So all you need to do to "merge" the subfolders is to open Domino Designer, open the user's mailbox, open the Folders, and then rename everything that starts with "CLIENTS2" so that they start with "CLIENTS" instead.

If you do that, then all you have to worry about is moving the documents from the top level folder the Notes client, and it's all done.

The answer to your question, though, is yes it can be done by scripting.  I'd start with the NotesNoteCollection class and go from there.  But since you are dealing with one user, I suspect the manual technique described above will be considerably faster.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out too. Problem is I never scripted in Lotus and the subfolders are too many to do that manually, plus it might turn out useful in the future to have such a script. I tried to script it out, but it is a bit too complex for a beginner, so I would really appreciate if someone could provide the script itself.

Comment: StackOverflow is a great place to come for help with specific problems in your own scripting. Many people here will help you if you try it yourself and have problems.  It's also reasonable to expect good hints to help you get started on something that you don't know enough about to research on your own. But it's not the place to come to get people to write an entire non-trivial script for you. That's outside of the intent of the site and the community here.